# Reading a certain pixels color from a window

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently reading a certain pixels color from a process window like this:

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
private static extern int BitBlt(IntPtr srchDc, int srcX, int srcY, int srcW, int srcH, 
                                 IntPtr desthDc, int destX, int destY, int op);

public static Color GetPixel(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y)
{
    var screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
    {
        using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(MemoryHandler.GetMainWindowHandle()))
        {
            IntPtr hsrcdc = gsrc.GetHdc();
            IntPtr hdc = gdest.GetHdc();
            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1, 1, hsrcdc, x, y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            gdest.ReleaseHdc();
            gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
        }
    }

    return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
}
```

It seems to be working.

I would like to know if I'm disposing everything that I use correctly to avoid memory leaks. If I inspect my app in the task manager I notice that the memory use is increasing a bit for each time i fetch a pixel, but I suppose the garbage collector will kick in when it's supposed to?

Also, is there any obvious "better" way of doing this?

Comment: You're not disposing the `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll actually need to wrap the `Bitmap` in a `using` as well because its base class, `Image`, implements `IDisposable`:

```
public static Color GetPixel(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y)
{
    using (Bitmap screenPixel = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    {
        using (Graphics gdest = Graphics.FromImage(screenPixel))
        {
            using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(MemoryHandler.GetMainWindowHandle()))
            {
                IntPtr hsrcdc = gsrc.GetHdc();
                IntPtr hdc = gdest.GetHdc();
                BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1, 1, hsrcdc, x, y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                gdest.ReleaseHdc();
                gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
            }
        }

        return screenPixel.GetPixel(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Further, the garbage collector works almost immediately. Or more simply put, if you use a memory allocation tool like MemProfiler, the memory will get cleaned up by GC faster than you can collect it with a snapshot. The `Bitmap` is likely where you are seeing the little tick.

It may also be worth wrapping the API call in a `try ... finally`:

```
IntPtr hsrcdc = gsrc.GetHdc();
IntPtr hdc = gdest.GetHdc();

try
{
    using (Graphics gsrc = Graphics.FromHwnd(MemoryHandler.GetMainWindowHandle()))
    {
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 1, 1, hsrcdc, x, y, (int)CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
    }
}
finally
{
    gdest.ReleaseHdc();
    gsrc.ReleaseHdc();
}
```

to ensure the `ReleaseHdc` gets called.

Comment: Yeah, the "not-disposing-the-bitmap"-part was a blunder on my end. However, after trying this yesterday (the disposing of the bitmap), the memory usage still increases with each timer tick that I run this in. I only tried running it for a few seconds, so perhaps the GC will kick in if I wait long enough? I don't see the point of the last code snippet. Can you give me an example where `gdest.ReleaseHdc(); gsrc.ReleaseHdc();` wouldn't get called? Thanks for the feedback - much appreciated!

Comment: @Johan, they wouldn't get called in the current code if an unhandled exception were thrown. Therefore, handling the possible exception means that even if an exception is thrown they'll get disposed.